# Crear nuevas columnas a partir de diferentes filas en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Llevo unos pensando como se podría hacer con pandas (es decir evitando el uso de bucles) el añadir una nueva columna en la que se tengan en cuenta valores de diferentes columnas pero que no estén en esa misma fila.

Por ejemplo, tenemos un dataframe:

```
data= {'C1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
       'C2': [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
       'C3': [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Y ahora quiero añadir la columna `Xn` donde esta equivaldría a `C1_actual * C3_2LineasDespués *50`

¿Cómo se podría hacer esto? ¿Que sucede cuando ya no hay líneas a futuro?

Yo con bucles lo conseguí y lo que hice fue eliminar las N filas finales a las que ya no se les puede aplicar la fórmula. ¿Se puede hacer lo mismo con pandas?

Resultado deseado:

```
C1  C2  C3  Xn
1   10  9   550
2   11  10  1200
3   12  11  1950
4   13  12  2800
5   14  13  3750
6   15  14  4800
7   16  15  5950
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift) para generar una serie de valores con un cierto "desplazamiento", en tu caso, por el ejemplo sería de una fila:

```
df["Xn"] = df["C1"] * df["C2"].shift(-1) * 50
```

Lo único que restaría, según tu planteo, sería eliminar la última fila:

```
df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
```